# Multiple Query on Firebase Collection

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am querying a firebase collection. I know individually these queries return the 1 record which exist, however together, they do not work. The query should return the one record where the date < the other date and the room equals the room number. The data is there, but does not work when the where statements are both in use:

```
    return this.afs.collection('/hotels').doc(hid).collection('reservations',ref=>ref
    .where(resdatefromto,'>=',reservationdate)
    .where('room','==',room)
    ).snapshotChanges();
 
   }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you're missing an index. For indexes on multiple fields, you need to have a composite index - which is not automatically created for you.

If this is indeed the problem, check the log output for an error message. In that error message you'll find a link, and clicking that link takes you to the Firebase console with all values to create the correct index pre-populated. All you have to do is click a button, and the necessary composite index will be created for you.

---

You may also first need to order on the `resdatefromto` field, before you can perform an `>=` filter on it. If that is the case, it will also be logged in an error message, and the solution is to call `.orderBy(resdatefromto)` before using that field in the `where` clause.